# how can i let my div act as a Link in react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I was doing a project where I was trying to get some of my divs that act as buttons to do some routing for me but it did not work.

some code snippets

```
<div className="central">
  <Mainview />
  <Post name='user' value='heloo there it works' likeCount={Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)} />
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/bookmarks' element={<Bookmarks />} />
  </Routes>
</div>
```

I want this div to change when I go to another route by clicking on another div that has a link like the following

```
function Bookmarks() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="book">
        <BookmarkIcon className='icon' />
        <h5 className='para'>Bookmarks</h5>
      
        <Link to='/Bookmarks'/>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

As you can see the div does not seem to be working or taking me to another component. What should I do?

Comment: The `div` elements in your code examples don't do anything. What exactly are you expecting to happen? Why not just use the `Link` component like it's intended to be used? Also, why is the `Bookmarks` component linking to the route rendering it?

Comment: You could put the link around your component or use the useNavigate hook to trigger navigation programatically :)

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

The main issue I see is that the `Link` component isn't wrapping any text or visual element

```
<Link to='/Bookmarks' />
```

so its size is effectively 0x0 and it becomes unclickable. There's no target for a user to click on to effect a navigation action.

## Solution

Wrap the *entire* `div` element in the link to make the `Bookmarks` component clickable.

```
function Bookmarks() {
  return (
    <Link to="....">
      <div className="book">
        <BookmarkIcon className='icon' />
        <h5 className='para'>Bookmarks</h5>
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
}
```

You could also use the `useNavigate` hook and attach an `onClick` handler to the `div` element, but this opens a can of worms regarding accessibility, i.e. you'd need to add an accessibility role, tab-index so the div is focusable, an `onKeyPress` handler, etc... It could be done, but using a link is just better in terms of semantic HTML.